# Posterized shadow pass in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

I rendered a shadow pass for my scene but unfortunately it is coming out a little odd compared to what I was hoping for. It looks posterized. Is there a way to fix this? I was looking for more of a smooth gradient of shadows.

[image]

Blend file: [image]

Comment: What would you like your shadow pass to look like? A black and white image determining were shadow is or not. Or would you like your original image in grayscale. Do have any example images of your desired look?

Comment: @Leander Something A smooth gradient from black -> white with grayscale in-between.

Comment: This is equivalent to your beauty pass in grayscale. It even says initial render, right? Do you simply wish to have a more shadow heavy light setup?

Comment: Sorry I missed that it said initial render on there. I guess you would get that look in the end by compositing all of the passes together and this is just what the shadow looks like when it is separated. I think I was just misunderstanding the process a little. Thanks for the help! I think I'm good now. I was just thinking about it wrong.

Comment: I think what I was thinking it the beauty pass was how the shadow pass was supposed to look.