# Firefly halo on glossy pass?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Is there any way to remove fireflies from the edges on a glossy direct pass? (At the very edges of the popcorn container and haloing the popcorn kernels in the front)

I set the samples to 2000 and filter glossy: 0.5 in the render below. The light is set to multiple importance on.[image: glossy direct]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to composite your scene. This may also resolve your other question: [Posterized shadow pass in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64310/posterized-shadow-pass-in-cycles?noredirect=1#comment110832_64310)

Since you only use Glossy and Diffuse shaders, we only need the glossy and diffuse passes enabled in the render passes.

[image: composite glossy and diffuse]

What you are experiencing are **not fireflies**. These artefacts will not be visible after the correct compositing.

The reason for that is the [premultiplication](http://www.spherevfx.com/written-training/miscellaneous-written-training/understanding-premultiplied-images/) of very transparent pixels after anti-aliasing.

In some edge pixels the popcorn overlaps the box. In a pixel which the box covers just slightly and which is mainly filled by a popcorn the glossy color of the box will be close to 0. The Glossy is going to be multiplied by the Glossy Color. Hence it needs to be **unpremultiplied**. There are plenty of tutorials on **premultiplication** and **unpremultiplication** in compositing and why they are important. Here is an explanation of the [technical background](https://compositing.wordpress.com/2010/09/13/premultiply-unpremultiply/). Color correction also only works with unpremultiplied data. Your scene is fine.

[image]